# Error sailsjs req.files is undifined?

Tags: sails.js

I am new in sailsjs. Plz help me fix the undefined issue.

I create the simple fileuplaoder using sails-local-fs adapter.

#### (view/uplaoder)

```
<form action = "/fileuploader" method="POST" id="upload-form">
   <input type="file" name="files" class="myfiles">
</form>
```

#### uploadController.js

```
'fileuploader': function(req.res)
    {
        sails.log("file uploading....");
        console.log(req.files); //this files display 
    }
```

#### photo.js

```
Photo.write(req.files)
    {
       container:public/uplaoder
    }
```

#### photo.js

```
adapter: 'sails-local-fs";
```

Please help me  fix the issue.
I want to  store the file in public / upload  path 
But  this code  `req.files` display  undefined error

Comment: Please provide more information on the error and what you've tried

Answer (score 2):

You are submitting the file without the form attribute `enctype`, `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

But again `req.files` no longer be used after v0.10-rc6 [Sails 0.10 req.files empty on file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780030/sails-0-10-req-files-empty-on-file-upload/23537118#23537118)
You will want to write code as

```
req.file('files').upload(function (err, uploadedFiles){
 var file1 = uploadedFiles[0];

});
```

The file will automatically be stored in '.tmp/uploads/' folder