# Sails 0.10 req.files empty on file upload

Tags: file-upload, express, sails.js

I'm doing a file upload to sails v0.10 via

```
POST /file/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

but the req.files object remains empty in sails

```
upload: function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.files);    // {}                                                                                                                            
}
```

in my file controller. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you performing the file upload?  With an HTML form?  With Postman?

Comment: Postman it is. I've also tried a basic html form, and my ajax form that used to work with 0.9.7+. This problem occurs with sails 0.10.0-rc4 out of the box.

Comment: You're just hitting `/file/upload` from Postman, using `form-data` mode and sending it a file?  That works fine for me...do you have any policies or other middleware that might be getting in the way?

Comment: I've just found the issue. Turns out it was human error on my side. I forgot to give the file a name in Postman and had broken something else on the client side so I wasn't feeding the html form the right stuff. Thanks for baring with me Scott.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @sgress454, Can you please help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609254/node-js-file-upload-buffers-in-memory-and-memory-not-freed-up-after-upload-is-d

Answer (score 5):

One should know that since sails v0.10-rc6 the Skipper-middleware is automatically used, so if you're having the same issue, don't use 'req.files' anymore but use the req.file('name') function (https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper)