# Node.js: file upload buffers in memory and memory not freed up after upload is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, heroku, sails.js

Using Sails.js to upload images to Azure with this code:

```
req.file('picture').upload({
      adapter: require('skipper-azure'),
      key: storageAccount,
      secret: accessKey,
      container: 'default'
    }, function(err, files) {
        if(!err) {
            return res.json(cdn + files[0].fd);
        } else {
            return res.send(err);
        }
    });
```

I have 2 problems:

- Files are buffered to memory instead of being streamed
- The memory is not freed-up when file upload is done, is it a Node.js problem, Sails.js', or my problem?

**UPDATE**

When I upload a 512MB file, I receive the following error on Heroku:

> 2016-01-05T17:17:18.083883+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13
> desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST
> path="/uploader/upload" host=abc.herokuapp.com
> request_id=fc2c32ed-35da-48de-8949-20f2a505d8eb fwd="41.35.30.180"
>
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=120024ms status=503 bytes=0
>
> 2016-01-05T17:17:18.081447+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
>
> 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089304+00:00 app[web.1]: Sending 500 ("Server
> Error") response: 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089309+00:00 app[web.1]:  Error:
> Request aborted 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089311+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
> IncomingMessage.onReqAborted
> (/app/node_modules/skipper/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:175:17)
>
> 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089311+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone
> (events.js:67:13) 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089312+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
> IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
>
> 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089313+00:00 app[web.1]:     at abortIncoming
> (_http_server.js:280:11) 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089314+00:00 app[web.1]:
> at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (_http_server.js:293:5)
>
> 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089314+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne
> (events.js:82:20)
>
> 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089315+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
> Socket.emit (events.js:169:7) 2016-01-05T17:17:18.089316+00:00
> app[web.1]:     at TCP._onclose (net.js:469:12) [Error: Request
> aborted]

Comment: The docs seem to indicate skipper-azure does indeed stream. What makes you believe otherwise? Memory will be freed up when the garbage collector runs and decides to free it, which could be long after the file upload is done.

Comment: @PeterLyons, thanks! Then, how can I explain that the whole file is uploaded to memory. I'm worried because this can crash my production

Comment: Streaming just means "many small buffers processed sequentially" instead of "one large buffer processed all at once", but either way all the data ends up in memory at some point and will eventually be freed by the garbage collector.

Comment: So, does this mean if I have a 1GB file to stream, the whole file will buffer to memory? I thought streaming is created to avoid this situation, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not all at once, but you might buffer 8KB chunks, process them, then let them go out of scope. Eventually the GC will run and free memory but not necessarily after each and every chunk is freed. You don't have direct control over how much memory v8 decides to use before running GC. Could be 10 MB, 100MB, etc.

Comment: @PeterLyons, please have a look to my question update. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99916/discussion-between-securecurve-and-peter-lyons).

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey @OliverMahoney, I skipped the upload library of sails entirely ... I found about alternative services to upload photos, we used FileStack and Cloudinary to do the upload job from the client side ... if you need further help, contact me to have a chat ..

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I think it's an issue related to garbage collection on Heroku, but still running tests to confirm. In the meantime i've added some workarounds to buy me some more time. Cheers!

Comment: @OliverMahoney, Heroku doesn't have a dedicated GC, probably you mean the Node engine.